# Problem with spaces when used in find command

Tags: shell, find, quoting, special-characters

I'm trying to place a zip file with the content of the directory in each directory that doesn't contain any subdirectory.

The following command works if there's no space in dirnames and/or filenames but fails if there are:

```
find pictures/ -type d -links 2 -execdir sh -c "pwd; echo '{}'; zip -v '{}/{}.zip' '{}/*' -x \*.zip -x \*.id" \;
```

I don't understand why it fails since I've quoted the '{}' as usual. Also tried "{}".
Said differently, it should create A/B/C/C.zip with the content of A/B/C/*. If there are spaces in 'C', I get:

```
zip warning: name not matched: ./C/*
zip error: Nothing to do! (./C/./C.zip)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With your version of `find`, the `{}` in the string is replaced by the file name. It is almost always an error to use `{}` as part of a string, because the file name is inserted just like that. Here, the file name is used as a shell script fragment. If there's a directory called `a'$(touch wibble)'` then your command executes the shell code

```
pwd; echo 'a'$(touch wibble)''; zip -v 'a'$(touch wibble)'/a'$(touch wibble)'.zip' 'a'$(touch wibble)'/*' -x \*.zip -x \*.id"`
```

Note how this executes the command `touch wibble` (four times).

You need to pass the file name as an argument to the shell snippet instead. That's the only way to use `find -exec` or `find -execdir` to call a shell reliably (except in cases where file names are constrained to have no special characters, including spaces). The first argument after `sh -c SCRIPT` can be accessed from the script as `"$0"`.

Furthermore `zip` doesn't accept wildcards in its list of files to zip, so the wildcard must be left unquoted, to be expanded by the shell.

```
find pictures/ -type d -links 2 -execdir sh -c 'pwd; echo "$0"; zip -v "$0/$0.zip" "$0/"* -x \*.zip -x \*.id' {} \;
```

Comment: That fixes the obvious problem, but still fails because of `"$0/*"`.  `zip` can't handle that.  `"$0"/*` is better but still wrong.  Thus `zip -r ... "$0"` instead of `zip ... "$0/*"`, which is basically my answer.

Comment: @SatoKatsura Ah, I hadn't spotted that, thanks. Why is `"$0"/*` wrong? That does something sensible, and I don't see any indication that it would not be what the asker wanted.

Comment: It would miss files `dir/.file`.

Comment: @SatoKatsura Sure, but that may have been by design. Some files are explicitly excluded and the zip is not recursive so the intent is not to store the whole directory. But anyway I think this is a peripheral issue, not related to the main point of the question which is safely getting a file name into a shell in `find -exec`.

Answer (score 2):

Change it like this:

```
find pictures -type d -links 2 -execdir \
    sh -c 'pwd; echo "$1"; zip -vr "$1/$1.zip" "$1" -x \*.zip -x \*.id' sh {} \;
```

Comment: Can you please explain what the sh at the very end does ?

Comment: The arguments for commands in `sh -c ...` start at 0.  The `sh` at the end provides a dummy `$0`, so that I can write `echo "$1" ...` rather than `echo "$0" ...`.  It looks slightly less confusing.